# Avoiding an unchecked cast for deepcopying map

Tags: java, unchecked

I'm trying to implement a deepCopy method for a multi valued map like this:

```
public static <K, V> ListValuedMap<K, V> deepCopy (ListValuedMap<K, V> a) {
    ListValuedMap<K, V> result = new ArrayListValuedHashMap<>();
    a.asMap().forEach((key, value) -> {
        Object newValue;
        if (value instanceof ListValuedMap) {
            newValue = deepCopy((ListValuedMap<K, V>) value);
                                 ‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾ 
                                    unchecked cast!

        } else if (value instanceof Cloneable) {
            try {
                Method clone = value.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("clone");
                newValue = clone.invoke(value);
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        } else {
            newValue = value;
        }
        result.put(key, (V) newValue);
                        ‾‾‾       
                  unchecked cast !
    });
    return result;
}
```

The second Unchecked cast can be avoided by passing the class for the `V` value type paramater argument and using `vClass.cast(newValue)`, but I have no idea on how to procede for the first error.

Comment: The first can be avoided by using `<?,?>`. The second cannot be avoided. Suppress it.

Comment: @Michael it's the other way around, the second maybe avoided using a class.cast the first one I cant see how

Comment: If you think the second can be avoided, why did you ask the question about it? It *can't* by the way.

Comment: result.put(key, vClass.cast(newValue)); doens't throw anything

Comment: You can't get V's class.

Comment: Unless I add it as a paramater